# How to properly pass `hstring` to FileTypeFilter() and FileTypeChoices()

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt, filepicker, react-native-windows

I made this code for opening file picker in [React Native for Windows](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/) app:

```
#pragma once

#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>

#include "pch.h"
#include "JSValue.h"
#include "NativeModules.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Microsoft::ReactNative;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Pickers;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;

namespace FilePicker
{
    REACT_MODULE(Panel);
    struct Panel
    {
        REACT_METHOD(Open, L"open");
        fire_and_forget Open(const hstring ext, React::ReactPromise<string> promise) noexcept
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker;
            openPicker.ViewMode(PickerViewMode::List);
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation(PickerLocationId::DocumentsLibrary);
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter().ReplaceAll({ ext });
            
            StorageFile file = co_await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file == nullptr) {
                promise.Reject("No file selected.");
            } else {
                promise.Resolve(to_string(file.Path()));
            }
        }

        REACT_METHOD(Save, L"save");
        fire_and_forget Save(const hstring ext, const hstring content) noexcept
        {
            FileSavePicker savePicker;
            savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation(PickerLocationId::DocumentsLibrary);
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices().Insert(ext, single_threaded_vector<hstring>({ ext }));
            
            StorageFile file = co_await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
            await FileIO::WriteTextAsync(file, content);
        }
    };
}
```

The app builds with no error, but when I run it and click button in app to trigger file picker, it crashes.
I googled it, and found it that FileOpenPicker and FileSavePicker crashes if file extension has not properly set.

I think `hstring` is right, since `wstring` and `wchar_t []` throws compile time error.
Then how can I pass it properly?

Comment: A crash means a lot of different things to a lot of different developers. Please be specific, and include the error diagnostic you get. I'm guessing that your program terminates because the file pickers are instantiated on a non-UI thread, which triggers a fail-fast exception that will take down the application. Passing the input by value is unrelated. It merely accomplishes that your program compiles. Prior to that you never got far enough to even observe run time behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable It just closes itself and only info I can get is `error code 0xc000027b` from `eventvwr.exe`. I'm still finding for more informations...
And if your guess is right, maybe [this](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/6339) would be related to my error?

Comment: Okay, I found a [document](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/native-modules-async#using-uidispatcher-with-cwinrt) from RNW... why didn't I found it earlier?

Comment: Now the file selecter works OK, but it crashes _after_...

Comment: That's... progress, at least. Try running your application under a debugger, and select the option to break into the debugger when an exception is *thrown*. I'm not familiar with React Native and don't know, what sorts of things can go wrong as part of transitioning back from the Windows Runtime into React Native code.