# How to reassign file to StorageFile at C++/WinRT

Tags: uwp, file-io, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, filepicker

I wrote a code which picks a file and wipe its content and save new one.
but it crashes when assigning file to `StorageFile`.

Note that this is excerpted code: full code is [here](https://github.com/jihoobyeon/react-native-file-panel/blob/main/windows/ReactNativeFilePanel/ReactNativeFilePanel.h).

```
#pragma once

#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>

#include "pch.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Pickers;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;

namespace MyFilePicker
{
  struct PickAndWrite
  {
    void Save(const hstring content) noexcept
    {
      StorageFile file = nullptr;

      picker([&file]()->fire_and_forget {
        FileSavePicker savePicker;
        file = co_await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync(); // crashes here.
      });

      writer([content, file]()->fire_and_forget {
        if (file != nullptr) { co_await FileIO::WriteTextAsync(file, content); }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

note that I can't unite `picker` and `writer`, because it is [related](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/10707#issuecomment-1278005213) with React Native.
then how can I assign it?

Comment: Isn't this just the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74011114/1889329) you'd asked about before?

Comment: @IInspectable yes, but in this case, I cannot pass `file` by value since `co_await` is complaining about it.
and React Native guys advised me to separate UI Thread and JS Thread, so I have to define `file` outside them.

Comment: A C++ coroutine can switch threads. C++/WinRT provides helper functions that allow you to switch to a specific thread. You could use [`resume_foreground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/resume-foreground) just before calling `PickSaveFileAsync()`, and then return to the thread you came from by saving the [`apartment_context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/apartment-context) on function entry and `co_await`-ing it. Now you're (presumably) back on your initial JS thread, where you can do the required bookkeeping.

Comment: [Programming with thread affinity in mind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind) is a fairly complete guide to all those concepts.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks to your advice, but it seems to be does not work at RNW. I found a solution -- there's a bug about `fire_and_forget` at RNW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. it was from a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows-samples/issues/603#issuecomment-973871084) of React Native for Windows.
Don't use `fire_and_forget` in RNW until the bug is gone.

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/jihoobyeon/react-native-file-panel/blob/main/windows/ReactNativeFilePanel/ReactNativeFilePanel.h) how I solved.